# python 2.7: List file in folder and subfolders and write them to file error

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I wrote this short code in python 2.7 and it should be listing all files and subfolders into a string. Then it multiply their ascii value by `multi` and concatenate it to `long_string`. Long string should be written to a file but it isn't happening i dont know why. can somebody help me?
There are no error message, the file is just not created.

`long_string` is 2 million characters long.

The code:

```
import os
from random import randint
username = ""
for name in ('LOGNAME', 'USER', 'LNAME', 'USERNAME'):
    if os.environ.get(name):
        username = os.environ.get(name)

long_string = ""

n = 10
multi = 12349790

filelist = os.popen("dir C:\users\%s\desktop /s /b"%(username)).read()
for c in filelist:
    number = str(ord(c)*multi)
    while len(number) < n:
        number = "0"+number
    long_string = long_string+number

with open("filelist.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(long_string)

a = [long_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(long_string), n)]

long_string2 = ""

for e in a:
    long_string2 = long_string2+chr(int(e)/multi)

lista_files = long_string2.split("\n")

print lista_files[:5]
```

Comment: are you sure you're looking in the right directory for `"filelist.txt"`?  maybe it is in another directory, you should write the complete path when creating a file.

Comment: i haven't thought about it. I'll try to change my code now.

Comment: The only lines relevant to your problem are `long_string = ""` and `with open("filelist.txt", "w") as outf: outf.write(long_string)`. You should be able to delete everything else and reproduce the problem. Is that correct? Also, how are you running the script? Where you run it from affects the default location to write files.